# Enabling free form windows in android O causes buttons in recent apps menu to overlap

Tags: huawei, multitasking, multi-window

I have searched for a way to enable free form windows. I've used the adb way,

```
adb shell settings put global enable_freeform_support 1
```

But I couldn't use it because the close button is overlapping free form button:

[image: screenshot]

My phone is Huawei P20 Lite (ANE-LX1) with EMUI 8.0.0 and android 8.0.0 with nova launcher.
Close button works like a charm when clicked

Any ideas what to do (rather than disabling the free form ) ?

It is okay to replace closing button with free form button if that's available.

Any solution without root is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my Huawei P10. I once used floating apps, which drained the battery, but now I use Launcher3-Freeform Launcher. Also, Taskbar is another choice for launching apps in freeform mode, although both Taskbar and Launcher3 are launchers and you need to launch your apps from these launchers to use the freeform mode.
Here are the links:

Floating Apps Free:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lwi.android.flapps

Taskbar:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farmerbb.taskbar

Launcher3-Freeform:
https://github.com/farmerbb/Launcher3-Freeform/blob/freeform-mode-example/README.md